# How to render a PHP file on windows?

Tags: php, windows

I'm trying to run a PHP file with HTML tags from the server on my computer. When i attempt to render the file in my browser my code is the only thing that appears. Does anyone know what the problem may be?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBe8a.png)

Answer (score -2):

PHP is a serverside programming language, meaning you can't see your PHP codes on a browser which is client-side. If you want to see some PHP codes, you would have to output them as strings e.g.

```
echo '        
    $test = 3;
    $test2 = 4;
    $solution = 7;        
';
```

should give: $test = 3; $test2 = 4; $solution = 7;